# calendar visibility

Tags: calendar, visibility

I have two users, Stefano Massoni and Alessando Mancini.

The calendar OWD is set on "Hide Details". Nevertheless Massoni can see the Mancini's details, while Mancini cannot see Massoni's details. Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to check if Massoni and Mancini have roles and if Massoni is the **manager** of Mancini in the *Role Hierarchy*. 
In that case you cannot avoid that he sees the Mancini's calendar, unless you remove the Role Hierarchy itself.